# REPO Error: HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden during firefox-compat install from AWS EC2 instance

Tags: yum, amazon-ec2, aws

tmp]$ sudo yum --enablerepo=epll install firefox-compat
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.lambda-linux.io/2018.03/epll/x86_64/os/mirror.list error was
14: HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden

One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
 1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

 2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

 3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
    just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
    --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

 4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true
```

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: epll/2018.03/x86_64

Comment: I have the same issue with a different epll repository (Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: epll/2017.09/x86_64) for installing the same firefox-compact. I followed the instructions on https://lambda-linux.io/#getting-started (EPLL REPOSITORY tab)